# Vue.js 2 Webpack 3 How to insert external .js from CDN into webpack externals?

Tags: webpack, vue.js

When we use a cdn library like jQuery instead of bundling it

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"
    integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

we have to include it as an external dependency :

```
externals: {
   jquery: 'jQuery'
}
```

then require it in the Vue.component

```
import $ from 'jquery';
..
$('.my-element').animate(...);
```

OK, but how do we find the module ID to insert into the externals ?

As an example, if I use the paypal api checkout.js

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
```

and I need to import it into my component vue

```
import paypal from 'paypal'
```

What is the module id to write in the webpack externals and where (how) can we find it from the paypal.js file content ?

externals: {
       paypal: 'checkout'. // or 'paypal-checkout' or 'paypal' ???
   },

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 4):

SOLVED ... using the html-webpack-externals-plugin package !

```
yarn add html-webpack-externals-plugin --dev
```

webpack.dev.conf.js

```
const HtmlWebpackExternalsPlugin = require('html-webpack-externals-plugin')
...
plugins: [
    ...
    new HtmlWebpackExternalsPlugin({
      externals: [
        {
          module: 'paypal',
          entry: 'https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js',
          global: 'paypal'
        }
      ]
    }),
...
```

index.html

```
  <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
```

Payments.vue component

```
<script>
  ....
  import paypal from 'paypal'
```

Comment: Just to point out that if the external webpack plugin is used it is not necessary to include the script tag into index.html

Comment: Does anyone use html-webpack-externals-plugin in vue-cli3.x, I found this plugin will insert my external file many times in the html file

Answer (score 1):

**html-webpack-externals-plugin** hasn't been updated for a long time and has a [bug](https://github.com/mmiller42/html-webpack-externals-plugin/issues/45).
If someone is using third-party lib such as "http://somedomain/plugin.js" (not cdn), you can use **[html-webpack-tags-plugin](https://github.com/jharris4/html-webpack-tags-plugin)**.  Its old name is **html-webpack-include-assets-plugin**, which is depended by **html-webpack-externals-plugin**.
I use it in vue-cli3.x with multiple pages, everything is OK.
***example***:

```
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackTagsPlugin({
        append: false, // append first
        publicPath: false, // remote lib doesn't use publicPath
        tags: [http://somedomain/plugin.js]
      })
    ]
```