# Webpack external JS file not defined when loaded in Vue.js 2 component

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I need to include a function from an external JS file in a Vue.js component. I've referenced [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48742906/4447791) to figure out how to load the external file in my webpack config. My current setup looks like this:

**webpack.dev.conf.js**

```
const HtmlWebpackExternalsPlugin = require('html-webpack-externals-plugin')

[...]

new HtmlWebpackExternalsPlugin({
  externals: [{
    module: 'iframeresize',
    entry: 'https://[...]/iframeResizer.min.js',
    global: 'iframeresize'
  }]
})
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://[...]/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
```

**.vue component**

```
import { iFrameResize } from 'iframeresize'

export default {
  name: 'FMFrame',
  mounted () {
    iFrameResize()
  }
}
```

However, I'm getting an error from vue-router now.

> [vue-router] Failed to resolve async component default:
>   ReferenceError: iframeresize is not defined
>
> [vue-router] uncaught error during route navigation:
>
> ReferenceError: iframeresize is not defined

Is there a step I'm missing in loading the function from the external file? I can use the function when loaded directly from `index.html`, but then I get a warning that the function is undefined as my webpack config seems to be ignored.

Comment: Just to point out that if the external webpack plugin is used it is not necessary to include the script tag into index.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is happening because you are using a "named" import. (e.g. with braces)

If you are going to use braces then the the named import must contain an export.

```
import {foo} from 'foo'
```

then foo.js should contain

```
export const foo = ...
```

So in your case you need to use a default import without the braces which will automatically get included in the `export default` statement.

Simply use the 'default' import syntax.

```
import foo from 'foo'
```

Not really all that important but just to help understanding, a default import can actually be imported with braces by using the special name `default`

```
import { default as foo } from 'foo';
```

Further if a module has several named exports in it you can import them all and then refer to them by property.

```
import * as foo from 'bar'; // has two named exports doThis and doThat

//reference the named exports later with.. 

foo.doThis();
foo.doThat();
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem could be the import expression, change with:

```
import iFrameResize from 'iframeresize'
```

**UPDATE**: just reproduced the problem and the above import works correctly.

**NOTE** Also remember to instantiate the plugin `HtmlWebpackExternalsPlugin` after your instance of html-webpack-plugin (see the [Usage section of the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-externals-plugin))

this is the plugin configuration that I've used (change the global option value):

```
new HtmlWebpackExternalsPlugin({
  externals: [
    {
      module: 'iframeresize',
      entry: 'https://<url_path>/iframeResizer.js',
      global: 'iFrameResize'
    }
  ]
}),
```